# BigQuery Auto-detect date format fails

Tags: date, datetime, format, google-bigquery

I have a CSV with dates in the form `/mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS AM` and
I'm trying to import it into BigQuery using AutoDetect.

BigQuery recognizes the field as a date, but then barfs when it tries to interpret AM or PM as a timezone:

> Invalid time zone: AM; Could not parse '02/15/2011 07:00:00 AM' as
>   datetime for field Date (position 2) starting at location NNNNNN

Answer (score 1):

That's not a timezone. Try importing as a STRING, then use `PARSE_DATE` (or `PARSE_TIMESTAMP`) to parse the STRING values as the desired type.

Comment: The problem is that I was using AutoDetect. BigQuery decided that it was a Date, then decided that it wasn't. If it can't handle the format then surely it should use String?
And yes I can work around the problem by defining the schema, but isn't that what AutoDetect is for?

Comment: As a counterexample, suppose that "AM" was "Amrica/Los_Angeles", which contains a misspelling. You would probably want to get back an error than to have autodetect assume that you wanted a string instead.